# How can I change the prompt to always show the current path?

Tags: fish

I want to continue using the fish shell with as little changes to default setup as possible.

But there is one thing that really bugs me. When the terminal window is cramped the prompt just becomes `>`. How can I change the prompt to make the current folder always show?

Comment: You might want to ask this on stackoverflow: more fish people will see your question there.

Answer (score 0):

In released versions, there is no way of preventing the shortening of the prompt when the terminal window is smaller than its length.

This behaviour has been altered in http://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/904 which will be present in upcoming releases.